# Flatten an array with forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, concatenation

After checking out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript) on flattening arrays, I noticed that no one had used the array method `forEach`. I gave it a try and failed, only receiving back an empty array:

```
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
let result = [];

arrays.forEach( (element) => {
    result.concat(element)
})

console.log(result) //[]
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to `result = result.concat(element)`

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
>   does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

```js
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
let result = [];

arrays.forEach((element) => {
  result = result.concat(element)
})

console.log(result) //[]
```

Doc: [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 3):

`.concat()` always returns a new array. It doesn't modify arrays on which it is operating.

You are supposing that `.concat()` will save result in its operand after completing its opeartion. However it is not the case. You need to save result explicitly after `.concat()`:

```
result = result.concat(element);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
let result = [];

arrays.forEach((element) => {
  result = result.concat(element)
});

console.log(result);
```

You can also use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of `.forEach()` to flatten array.

```
let result = [].concat(...arrays);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
let result = [].concat(...arrays);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns a new array and hence you need to assign it to result like `result = result.concat(element)`

```js
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
let result = [];

arrays.forEach( (element) => {
    result = result.concat(element)
})

console.log(result)
```